# How to limit character input "cin" to get just one string

Tags: c++, string, input, cin

I was writing this code for training, and I'm in a problem where if my user write his name followed by a space and something else, the program will mess up my flow. So it's easier if you try the little program and when it ask for name, put like "Robert Red". The problem occurs just when you put something else after the space, if you input just "Robert" all goes good.

This is the code:

```
// Description:  This is a simple replica of the Japanese game Rock, Paper and
// Scissors.
// Author: Ernesto Campese
// Last Update: 11/04/2018
// Version: 0.0.1

#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int main() {

    string username = "";
    char userinput;
    int rounds = 0;
    int wins = 0;
    int draws = 0;
    int loses = 0;
    int user_secret = 0;
    vector<string> options = {"Paper", "Scissors", "Rock"};

    cout << "Enter your name: ";
    cin >> username;
    cout << "Welcome " << username << ", this is the game of Rock, Paper and Scissors.\n";
    cout << username << " how many rounds you want to do? ";
    cin >> rounds;
    if (rounds <= 0) {
      cout << "You need to play at least one round!\n";
      rounds++;
    }
    cout << "The game is based on " << rounds << " rounds, you versus the CPU.\n";
    cout << "Are you ready? (y/n): ";
    cin >> userinput;

    if (userinput != 'y') {
      cout << "\nThank you.\nProgram Terminated by " << username;
      return 0;
    }

    for(int i = 1; i <= rounds; i++) {
      // Title of the rounds
            if (i == 1) {
                cout << "\nLet's start the first round!\n";
            } else {
                cout << "Round n. " << i << " begins!\n";
            }

            // USER makes a move
            cout << "Which is your move? (r,p,s):  ";
            cin >> userinput;
            cout << '\n' << username << " says... ";
            switch (userinput) {
            case 'r':
                cout << "Rock\n";
                user_secret = 2;
                break;
            case 'p':
                cout << "Paper\n";
                user_secret = 0;
                break;
            case 's':
                cout << "Scissors\n";
                user_secret = 1;
                break;
            default:
                cout << "something weird...\n";
                break;
            }

            // CPU makes a move
            int cpu_secret = rand() % 3;
            cout << "CPU says... " << options[cpu_secret] << "!\n";

            // The program calculates the result.
            if (user_secret == cpu_secret) {
          draws++;
                cout << username << " and the CPU draws!\n\n";
        } else if (user_secret == 0 && cpu_secret == 2) {
            wins++;
                cout << username << " wins!\n\n";
        } else if (user_secret == 1 && cpu_secret == 0) {
            wins++;
                cout << username << " wins!\n\n";
        } else if (user_secret == 2 && cpu_secret == 1) {
            wins++;
                cout << username << " wins!\n\n";
        } else {
          loses++;
                cout << username << " lose!\n\n";
        }
    }

        cout << "\n\nBattle End!\n";
        if (wins > loses) {
            cout << username << " won the battle!\n";
        } else if (loses > wins) {
            cout << username << " lost the battle!\n";
        } else {
            cout << username << " draws the battle!\n";
        }
        cout << "Thank you " << username << "!\n";

}
```

You can try it here: [Try me](https://repl.it/@ErnestoCampese/Rock-Paper-and-Scissors)
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the user to be able to type in a name that has spaces in it, use [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead of `operator>>`:

```
getline(cin, username);
```

Otherwise, if you want the user to enter only 1 word for the name, and you want to ignore anything else the user may enter, use [`std::cin.ignore()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore):

```
#include <limits>
...

cin >> username;
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Alternatively, you can use `std::getline()` to read a line, and then use [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) with `operator>>` to extract the 1st word of the line:

```
#include <sstream>
...

string line;
getline(cin, line);
istringstream(line) >> username;
```

Comment: Wow thanks is working, actually my goal was the second one! Now i got to study this function "cin.ignore..."

Answer (score 3):

`operator>>` stops reading input when it finds a whitespace character.

Use `std::getline()` to read user input with spaces.

Example using your code:

```
cout << "Enter your name: ";
getline(cin, username);
```